# How do I find the error at a line number in a Oracle Live SQL script?

Tags: oracle, errors

When someone runs an Oracle Live SQL script, each statement is executed and the final result (or errors) are displayed below each statement. However, line number errors create a bit of an issue:

[image]

The line number states is 77, however this is the 157th statement, hence one does not know what line 77 refers to.  Where can a user find a specific line number in Oracle Live SQL?

Comment: This might help. https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CSBE3ZJTSXBTUEI174J84WGO0.html

Comment: Have you tried using  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(**LineNumberHere**)); ?  I just tried it in Live SQL and it worked.  Edit, nvmd, I like @SqlWorldWide 's answer.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide this seems to work only for stored procedures.

Comment: @MguerraTorres  what do you expect from DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(LineNumberHere))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to find errors within a Trigger within Oracle Live SQL is as follows:

```
Select * 
from
     user_errors
```

This is how Ricardo Araujo debugged his Compound trigger error in statement 22 of his Oracle Live Sql [script](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_EKIGUFWU83SYM94L80IEW0O39.html).